# Spring Inject Autowired SessionAttribute into Service Layer

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to `@Inject/@Autowired` a SessionAttribute into the `@Service` layer directly without passing it through a `@Controller`?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
@Autowired 
@SessionAttribute("userprincipal") 
UserPrincipal principal;
```

Possible Solution:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public UserPrincipal sessionUserPrincipal() {
        // not sure here the user does not exist at creation of bean
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do that; it's a hidden dependency that makes your code a serious pain to test and refactor.

Comment: @chrylis How is it hidden? It's an autowired dependency, just as any other autowired dependency. The fact that it's session-scoped doesn't change anything to how you would test it.

Comment: @Vlad AFAIK you can't autowired a session atttribute. But you can declare a session-scoped bean, store anything you want in it, and inject the bean where you need it. Beware that if you ever try to use this dependency outside of a request-handling thread, you'll get an exception (for example, in a scheduled method, or in an async method).

Comment: @JBNizet _Field-injected_ dependencies are hidden because they don't appear in the object's public API; this is exactly why they're recommended against as a best practice. Per-request dependencies compound the opacity by pretending to be, but not actually being, stable.

Comment: I agree about field injection, but that's true whatever the scope of the injected bean is. I disagree with the rest: if some immutable value exists in all requests (like the current user, which seems to be what the OP wants to inject), I find it safe and simpler to inject it than to pass it as argument of each and every method.

Comment: @JBNizet how you would go about setting this up in ApplicationConfig the user does not exist at time of `@Bean` creation?

Comment: Just like you would, somewhere, store the user in a session attribute (once logged in, probably), you would srore it in that bean instead (using a method of that bean)

Answer (score 0):

My solution, hopefully this will save someone else some time.

Caution: The injected dependency is hidden, this will cause problems if used outside a session. Use `Optional<T>` if this is the case and handle internally. If you share your code your team will not be aware of the required dependency.

Testing: When testing you will be required to provide the session bean for `@Autowired` functionality.

Session Bean Class:

```
public class SessionUserPrincipal implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private UserPrincipal principal;

    public SessionUserPrincipal() {}

    // mutator methods omitted
}
```

return `Optional<T>` if session attribute is not guarantied to be available

Add Bean to Context:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServletContextConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public SessionUserPrincipal sessionUserPrincipal() {
        return new SessionUserPrincipal();
    }
}
```

Add RequestContextListener to web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

this is a requirement for the code below to work. It exposes state necessary to implement session scope. By default that state is exposed by DispatcherServlet, so it's not available before request enters DispatcherServlet (Spring Security filters). You will get an exception if you try to `@Autowire` a session bean before its available.

Add session attribute to session `@Bean` on successful authentication.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Autowired SessionUserPrincipal sessionUserPrincipal;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        // find/get userprincipal code omitted
        sessionUserPrincipal.setPrincipal(userprincipal);
    }
}
```

Use session bean:

```
@Service
public class DefaultSomeService implements SomeService {
    @Autowired private SessionUserPrincipal sessionUserPrincipal;
}
```